# Clipping or Erasing area in threejs

Tags: three.js

[image]

First I am explaining the above image. Image is marking  with 1, 2 and 3.

1 - This is the rectangle shape.

2 - This is the rectangle shape.

3 - This is the circle shape (draw with destination-in global composite operation).

Every shape draw using HTML5 canvas.

Now I want to same draw using threejs with WebGLRenderer. So is it possible to draw? If yes then how?

3rd shape can be anything (for ex - circle, rectangle, polygon).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

We can erase an area in threejs by set the blending property. In threejs different types of blending property available. For example THREE.SubtractiveBlending which is use to subtract the area.

For details  -

```
   1) http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Constants/Materials  
   2) http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_blending  
   3) http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_blending_custom
```

Answer (score -2):

To draw using WebGLRenderer, is basically changing the canvas by:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

Just beware of the methods of Canvas that do not exist in WebGLRenderer.

If you show as part of the code, it would be good to give more precision. But anything, just comment here!

Comment: Is it possible some erasing or clipping any type of shape from the scene in three js (erasing  or clipping like posted image)?